# Create XML nodes using XPath

Tags: c++, xml, qt, xpath

Is it possible to create `XML` nodes using `XPath`?

Assume i got the following XML:

```
<data>
    <someValue1></someValue2>
    <someValue2></someValue2>
    <someArray>
        <val></val>
        <val></val>
        <val></val>
    </someArray>
</data>
```

What I am trying to do is getting a node inside the `XML` using `XPath` (e.g. `/data/someValue1`) and setting the value of the node. This is of course easy to achieve with any language and framework supporting `XML` + `XPath`.

**But when my `XPath` expression is pointing to a non existing node I want to somehow create this node.** Even if the `XPath` expression is more complex (*e.g.* `/data/someArray/val[5]`).

At best this automatic node creation should be supported by some library. Is there an easy way for what I am trying to achieve? Currently I am using **C++** with **Qt** and the `QXmlQuery` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to create XML nodes using XPath?

No, it isn't. XPath can only select existing nodes.

If you want to create new nodes, you need XSLT or XQuery.

But even then, creating a node that satisfies a given path like `/a/b/c/foo[5]` is non-trivial, and not something that the languages can do automatically.